# How to get the previous selected value from a dropdown before onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I know its the easiest question but can't get the correct answer.

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-5 mt10-xs">
     <p>Status</p>
     <div class="form-group FL mr20 w100-xs">
           <div class="rsi-custom-select">
                 <select class="form-control" id="statustab_{{ $row['placementkey'] }}" class="select2-selecting" onchange="listingByStatus(this,'{{ $row['placementkey'] }}')">
                     @foreach($placementStatus as $pl)
                        <option @if($pl['placement_status_id'] ==  $row['statusid'] ) selected @endif value="{{$pl['placement_status_key']}}">{{$pl['placement_status']}}</option>
                     @endforeach
                 </select>
            </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

This is my `onchange` function. In this How Can I get the previous Selected Value from my select box?

```
function listingByStatus(ths,key){
      var thisSelect = $('#statustab_'+key).text();
      var statusText = $( "#statustab_"+key+" option:selected" ).text();
      var currentval = $( "#statustab_"+key+" option:selected" ).val();
}
```

Comment: Set your value on some where hidden filed or local storage and get previous value from them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Save the original value using `data()` when the element gets focus:**

```
$('.select2-selecting').on('focusin', function(){
    console.log("Saving value " + $(this).val());
    $(this).data('val', $(this).val());
});
```

**And then get the saved old value in your `onchange` function:**

```
function listingByStatus(ths,key){
         var thisSelect = $('#statustab_'+key).text();
         var statusText = $( "#statustab_"+key+" option:selected" ).text();
         var currentval = $( "#statustab_"+key+" option:selected" ).val();
         var prev = $('.select2-selecting').data('val'); //old value
         console.log("Old value " + prev);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your responce, But cant get the valid answer. If i alert 'prev' it show undefined

Comment: Still Same Bro.

Comment: thanks alot bro i get the answer. thank you for your response

Answer (score 6):

You could include a hidden input field on your page

```
<input type="hidden" id="previous_value" name"previous_value" value="abc"/>
```

Then in your script you could access as any other input:

```
var previous = $('#previous_value').val();
```

Set it after an onchange event occurs:

```
$('#statustab_{{ $row['placementkey'] }}').addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    $('$previous_value').val(e.value)
})
```

Comment: In this i get value like this "sdf7327y773 ". its very risky to check in if condition. Any Alternative Solution Bro.

Comment: What type of value are you expecting? I'll edit my answer accordingly

Comment: Bro I follow Your Method and get the correct answer. Thanks alot

Comment: What's the point in using an element if you're using javascript anyway? Just remember the value.

Answer (score 4):

1. Use the `data-*` to store the old value
2. Get the `data-*` as the old value and the selected option as new value

```js
$('select').change(function(){
var oldvar = $(this).attr('data-old') !== typeof undefined? $(this).attr('data-old') :"";
var newval = $("option:selected",this).text();
$(this).attr('data-old',newval)
console.log("prev value :" + oldvar)
console.log("curr value :" + newval)
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Combine the `focus` event with the change event to achieve what you want:

Try like this:

```js
(function () {
    var previous;

    $("select[name=test]").focus(function () {
        // Store the current value on focus, before it changes
        previous = this.value;
    }).change(function() {
        // Do something with the previous value after the change
        document.getElementById("oldData").innerHTML = "<b>Previous: </b>"+previous;
        
        previous = this.value;
    });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="test">
    <option value="one">one</option>
    <option value="two">two</option>
    <option value="three">three</option>
    <option value="four">four</option>
</select>
<div id="oldData"></div>
```

This will give you the last value which is selected.

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 1):

Try below code. Hope it will help you.

```js
$('select').change(function(){
  var oldval = $(this).prop('data-old') !== undefined ? $(this).prop('data-old') : "";
  var newval = $("option:selected",this).text();
  console.log("previous value : " + oldval);
  console.log("current value : " + newval);
  $(this).prop('data-old',newval);
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Mango</option>
  <option>Banana</option>
  <option>Orange</option>
</select>
```